# The Navigator in my RCP app is always empty

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I was switching from Eclipse Kepler to Eclipse 2018-09. All is OK so far except on thing: The Navigator is now always empty.

I have the popup menu and I am able to create a project. The project is created and I can use it intern in my code with no problems. But the navigator shows nothing except an empty menu Item. if I right click on it I have the popupmenue for the project. I can close the project for example and all other. But the menu item diesn't show any text.

If I refresh the Navigator then the menu item disappears and also does not show up anymore when I restart my app.

Any idea? Thanks

edit:

I created a new project and used the mail-demo application. Then I added the navigator plugin and navigator resources. Same problem. Then I added java support and now there is the same problem in the "save and launch" dialog.

[image: Screenshot with Error]

edit2:

I had nor error of missing plugins. But as test I added every single plugin to the app but the navigator was still empty. Then I remember that I had to add an Hack in Kepler. As test I took the hack out and the Navigation was empty in Kepler as well.

The problem now is that **WorkbenchAdapterBuilder.registerAdapters();** in preStartup() is not available anymore and if I take it out the Navigation is empty again.

```
import java.net.URL;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.IAdaptable;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Path;
import org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform;
import org.eclipse.jface.resource.ImageDescriptor;
import org.eclipse.ui.application.IWorkbenchConfigurer;
import org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor;
import org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEInternalWorkbenchImages;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchPlugin;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.model.WorkbenchAdapterFactory;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;

/**
 * Methods copied from {@link org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor}
 */
@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public abstract class WorkbenchAdvisorHack extends WorkbenchAdvisor {
    /**
 * Declares all IDE-specific workbench images. This includes both "shared"
 * images (named in {@link IDE.SharedImages}) and internal images (named in
 * {@link org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEInternalWorkbenchImages}).
 * 
 * @see org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor#declareImage
 */
protected void declareWorkbenchImages() {
    final String ICONS_PATH = "$nl$/icons/full/";//$NON-NLS-1$
    final String PATH_ELOCALTOOL = ICONS_PATH + "elcl16/"; // Enabled
    // //$NON-NLS-1$

    // toolbar
    // icons.
    final String PATH_DLOCALTOOL = ICONS_PATH + "dlcl16/"; // Disabled
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // toolbar
    // icons.
    final String PATH_ETOOL = ICONS_PATH + "etool16/"; // Enabled toolbar
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // icons.
    final String PATH_DTOOL = ICONS_PATH + "dtool16/"; // Disabled toolbar
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // icons.
    final String PATH_OBJECT = ICONS_PATH + "obj16/"; // Model object
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // icons
    final String PATH_WIZBAN = ICONS_PATH + "wizban/"; // Wizard
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // //$NON-NLS-1$
    // icons

    Bundle ideBundle = Platform.getBundle(IDEWorkbenchPlugin.IDE_WORKBENCH);

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_BUILD_EXEC, PATH_ETOOL + "build_exec.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_BUILD_EXEC_HOVER, PATH_ETOOL + "build_exec.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_BUILD_EXEC_DISABLED, PATH_DTOOL + "build_exec.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_SEARCH_SRC, PATH_ETOOL + "search_src.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_SEARCH_SRC_HOVER, PATH_ETOOL + "search_src.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_SEARCH_SRC_DISABLED, PATH_DTOOL + "search_src.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_NEXT_NAV, PATH_ETOOL + "next_nav.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_PREVIOUS_NAV, PATH_ETOOL + "prev_nav.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_WIZBAN_NEWPRJ_WIZ, PATH_WIZBAN + "newprj_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_WIZBAN_NEWFOLDER_WIZ, PATH_WIZBAN + "newfolder_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_WIZBAN_NEWFILE_WIZ, PATH_WIZBAN + "newfile_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_WIZBAN_IMPORTDIR_WIZ, PATH_WIZBAN + "importdir_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_WIZBAN_IMPORTZIP_WIZ, PATH_WIZBAN + "importzip_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_WIZBAN_EXPORTDIR_WIZ, PATH_WIZBAN + "exportdir_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_WIZBAN_EXPORTZIP_WIZ, PATH_WIZBAN + "exportzip_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_WIZBAN_RESOURCEWORKINGSET_WIZ, PATH_WIZBAN + "workset_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_DLGBAN_SAVEAS_DLG, PATH_WIZBAN + "saveas_wiz.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_DLGBAN_QUICKFIX_DLG, PATH_WIZBAN + "quick_fix.png", false); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT, PATH_OBJECT + "prj_obj.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OBJ_PROJECT_CLOSED, PATH_OBJECT + "cprj_obj.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OPEN_MARKER, PATH_ELOCALTOOL + "gotoobj_tsk.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ELCL_QUICK_FIX_ENABLED, PATH_ELOCALTOOL + "smartmode_co.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_DLCL_QUICK_FIX_DISABLED, PATH_DLOCALTOOL + "smartmode_co.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$

    // task objects
    // declareRegistryImage(IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_HPRIO_TSK,
    // PATH_OBJECT+"hprio_tsk.gif");
    // declareRegistryImage(IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_MPRIO_TSK,
    // PATH_OBJECT+"mprio_tsk.gif");
    // declareRegistryImage(IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_LPRIO_TSK,
    // PATH_OBJECT+"lprio_tsk.gif");

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OBJS_TASK_TSK, PATH_OBJECT + "taskmrk_tsk.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDE.SharedImages.IMG_OBJS_BKMRK_TSK, PATH_OBJECT + "bkmrk_tsk.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_COMPLETE_TSK, PATH_OBJECT + "complete_tsk.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_INCOMPLETE_TSK, PATH_OBJECT + "incomplete_tsk.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_WELCOME_ITEM, PATH_OBJECT + "welcome_item.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_WELCOME_BANNER, PATH_OBJECT + "welcome_banner.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_ERROR_PATH, PATH_OBJECT + "error_tsk.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_WARNING_PATH, PATH_OBJECT + "warn_tsk.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_OBJS_INFO_PATH, PATH_OBJECT + "info_tsk.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$

    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_LCL_FLAT_LAYOUT, PATH_ELOCALTOOL + "flatLayout.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_LCL_HIERARCHICAL_LAYOUT, PATH_ELOCALTOOL + "hierarchicalLayout.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_ETOOL_PROBLEM_CATEGORY, PATH_ETOOL + "problem_category.gif", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    //declareWorkbenchImage(ideBundle, IDEInternalWorkbenchImages.IMG_LCL_LINKTO_HELP, PATH_ELOCALTOOL + "linkto_help.gif", false); //$NON-NLS-1$
}

/**
 * Declares an IDE-specific workbench image.
 * 
 * @param symbolicName
 *          the symbolic name of the image
 * @param path
 *          the path of the image file; this path is relative to the base of
 *          the IDE plug-in
 * @param shared
 *          <code>true</code> if this is a shared image, and
 *          <code>false</code> if this is not a shared image
 * @see org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor#declareImage
 */
private void declareWorkbenchImage(Bundle ideBundle, String symbolicName, String path, boolean shared) {
    URL url = FileLocator.find(ideBundle, new Path(path), null);
    ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
    getWorkbenchConfigurer().declareImage(symbolicName, desc, shared);
}

@Override
public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setSaveAndRestore(true);
    declareWorkbenchImages();
}

@Override
public IAdaptable getDefaultPageInput() {
    return new NavigatorRoot();
}

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
@Override
public void preStartup() {
    WorkbenchAdapterBuilder.registerAdapters();
}
```

}

Comment: Check that you are including all the required plugins in the RCP - they will have changed between Kepler and 2018-09. How are you initializing this RCP - do you have your own 'IApplication'?

Comment: Please see edit2 in my post - thanks

Comment: You are probably going to have to read through the source of `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEWorkbenchAdvisor` to see what it now does. A lot of what you are using is 'internal' so the Eclipse developers are free to change it as they like.

Comment: Thank you Greg - I'll try this.

But I have a hard time to believe thatbthis is necessary just to use the build in Navigator or CommonNavigator.

Why is this - what am I missigng? Is it not ment to use the Navigator in projects? Is someone using the Navigator without problems?

Thanks

Comment: Those classes expect to run in a full Eclipse install, they aren't designed to be used in an RCP so you have to copy the setup stuff done by the full Eclipse.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

in `ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor` add

```
@Override
public void initialize(IWorkbenchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setSaveAndRestore(true);
    IDE.registerAdapters();
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding explanation to your answer